# TypeError: Object of type ReplyKeyboardMarkup is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

````
from telegram.ext import CallbackContext    
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import Filters
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import KeyboardButton



button = 'Кнопка'

def messagehandler (update: Update,conext: CallbackContext):
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=[
               [
        KeyboardButton(text=button)
               ],   
        ],
        resize_keyboard = True,
        ),
    update.message.reply_text(
        text='Привет',
        reply_markup = reply_markup,
        )


def main ():
    print('start')
    updater = Updater(
       token = '1316145158:AAF2hFXftyoA0rPbv4b_I1rTFMca',
       use_context=True,)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters=Filters.all, callback= messagehandler))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
      ```


Что делать?
````

Comment: Может хоть токен скроете? Хотя уже лучше делать новый.

Comment: Я удалил последние несколько символов. Ничего страшного не будет

Answer (score 0):

Наткнулся на подобную ошибку. Вот решение.

Вместо ReplyKeyboardMarkup следует использовать types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup:

```
keyboard_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True,)
keyboard_markup.add(types.KeyboardButton(text=button))

update.message.reply_text(
    text='Привет',
    reply_markup=reply_markup,
)
```

https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/regular_keyboard_example.py